# Passing null in Highcharts line graphs

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

So I have to pass an array in javascript to the Highcharts y-axis and there are some cases in which for an x-axis value, there isn't supposed to be a y-axis value. So, the graph should join the previous point to the next point.

From my search, I found this solution on stack overflow -> [missing value in highcharts line graph results in no line, just points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123163/missing-value-in-highcharts-line-graph-results-in-no-line-just-points/15123478#15123478)

From the comments, apparently the null solution should be working but if you open that js fiddle, you'll see a broken line. At-least, that's what I'm seeing. Also, please see my jsfiddle file: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xLaxL0e/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            crosshair: true
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, null, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

You can see, there's a broken line here too if we pass null!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to connect null values as well use connectNull:true

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            connectNulls: true
        }
    }
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/6xLaxL0e/1/)