# Highcharts: How to divide line graph when there's a gap in the x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So basically this is what I want to do:
[image: Graph]

There's a gap in the x axis between week 27 and week 32 which you can't really see if you don't look closely. I would like to cut the line graph in two to indicate that there is data missing.

I've seen examples like this one
[image: Graph2]
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123478/1652348)

but I would prefer to not add all the empty weeks to the x axis (in order to save space).

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you can't split your data into two series, or add null values when you don't have your data?

Comment: I made an attempt  and it works ok: http://jsfiddle.net/555Lcrbb/ It feels like a lot of job though. No easier way?

Comment: You can do it in just one series: http://jsfiddle.net/555Lcrbb/1/

Comment: Ah, yes of course! Since I'm adding the categories my self. Good idea! Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add null values for the weeks that don't have their own values. Adding null values will break your spline series just like you want.

Here you can find the code that can help you making your chart:

```
{
      data: [65, 76, 70.3, 79.3, null, 53.5, 77.7],
}
```

and here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/555Lcrbb/2/

Comment: I just realized that your solution isn't really working. In your example there is no data for week 27.

Comment: It was just a simple example of using null to split your lines. You can add your value another way. I think that should meet your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/555Lcrbb/3/